# Spring Boot application logs show iRAv2 format logs

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Here is a weird issue. I have a Spring Boot application with different branches. All of a sudden one of the feature branch shows logs in iRAv2 format (shown below) and skips some of the original log messages from the actual log messages. I do not use any specific logging library other than the Spring Boot default

**iRAv2 format logs:**

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.2.RELEASE)

Jan 02 10:34:23 [iRAv2] Starting PresApplication on testhostname with PID 20704 | o.s.boot.StartupInfoLogger:55 
Jan 02 10:34:23 [iRAv2] No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default | o.s.boot.SpringApplication:651
```

**Correct format logs:**

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.2.RELEASE)

2020-01-02 10:37:36.454  INFO 20937 --- [           main] g.c.c.o.l.patientreg.PresApplication     : Starting PresApplication on testhostname with PID 20937
2020-01-02 10:37:36.459  INFO 20937 --- [           main] g.c.c.o.l.patientreg.PresApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-01-02 10:37:37.435  INFO 20937 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-01-02 10:37:37.442  INFO 20937 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-01-02 10:37:37.443  INFO 20937 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.29]
2020-01-02 10:37:37.680  INFO 20937 --- [           main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner     : At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
2020-01-02 10:37:37.683  INFO 20937 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
```

Comment: what files have been changed in that feature branch?

Comment: What is iRAv2? Do you use this anywhere in the app?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli No, I do not use this anywhere. Actually I don't know what it is

Comment: @DavidLavender I compared both the branches, no differences

Comment: Are you running this with just `java -jar` ?

Comment: @DavidLavender I am just running it through IntelliJ, which of course uses same command

Comment: @DavidLavender I figured out the issue. One of the 3rd party library causing this issue. But the issue is not consistent, meaning I have that library in development and master, where I do not see any issue. Anyway I defined custom logback.xml for time being.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always define your logging pattern in `application.properties`.

Comment: I get that. I just want to use default spring-boot logging pattern instead of defining my own format

Comment: It turns out one of the dependency libraries developer defined iRAV2 format in his `logback.xml` file which caused this issue. Now I have to override the logback.xml file